# wildfly-8.2.0.Final is not creating proper access-logs

Tags: logging, wildfly-8, access-log

I am using wildfly-8.2.0.Final in that I have made following configuration in the Standalone.xml.

```
<pre> Standalone.xml<code>  
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.2">

        <extensions>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
            <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
            <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch"/>
            <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
            <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
        </extensions>


        <management>
            <security-realms>
                <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                    <authentication>
                        <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                        <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                    </authentication>
                    <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                        <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-realm>
                <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                    <authentication>
                        <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                        <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                    </authentication>
                    <authorization>
                        <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-realm>
            </security-realms>
            <audit-log>
                <formatters>
                    <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
                </formatters>
                <handlers>
                    <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </handlers>
                <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                    <handlers>
                        <handler name="file"/>
                    </handlers>
                </logger>
            </audit-log>
            <management-interfaces>
                <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
                    <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
                </http-interface>
            </management-interfaces>
            <access-control provider="simple">
                <role-mapping>
                    <role name="SuperUser">
                        <include>
                            <user name="$local"/>
                        </include>
                    </role>
                </role-mapping>
            </access-control>
        </management>

        <profile>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
                <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                    <level name="INFO"/>
                    <formatter>
                        <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                    </formatter>
                </console-handler>
                <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                    <formatter>
                        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                    </formatter>
                    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                    <append value="true"/>
                </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
                <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="ACCESSFILE" autoflush="true">
                    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="access-log.log"/>
                    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                    <append value="true"/>
                </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
                <logger category="com.arjuna">
                    <level name="WARN"/>
                </logger>
                <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                    <level name="WARN"/>
                </logger>
                <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                    <level name="DEBUG"/>
                </logger>
                <logger category="sun.rmi">
                    <level name="WARN"/>
                </logger>
                <logger category="jacorb">
                    <level name="WARN"/>
                </logger>
                <logger category="jacorb.config">
                    <level name="ERROR"/>
                </logger>
               <logger category="io.undertow.server.handlers.accesslog" use-parent-handlers="false">
                    <level name="INFO"/>
                    <handlers>
                        <handler name="ACCESSFILE"/>
                    </handlers>
                </logger>
                <root-logger>
                    <handlers>
                        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                        <handler name="FILE"/>
                    </handlers>
                </root-logger>

                <formatter name="PATTERN">
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch:1.0">
                <job-repository>
                    <in-memory/>
                </job-repository>
                <thread-pool>
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
                <datasources>
                    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                        <driver>h2</driver>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>sa</user-name>
                            <password>sa</password>
                        </security>
                    </datasource>
                    <drivers>
                        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                        </driver>
                    </drivers>
                </datasources>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
                <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="0" auto-deploy-exploded="true"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
                <global-modules>
                    <module name="configuration" slot="main"/>
                </global-modules>
                <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
                <concurrent>
                    <context-services>
                        <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                    </context-services>
                    <managed-thread-factories>
                        <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                    </managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-executor-services>
                        <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="5" max-threads="25" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                    </managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                        <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="2" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                    </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                </concurrent>
                <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:2.0">
                <session-bean>
                    <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
                    <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
                </session-bean>
                <pools>
                    <bean-instance-pools>
                        <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                        <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    </bean-instance-pools>
                </pools>
                <caches>
                    <cache name="simple"/>
                    <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
                </caches>
                <passivation-stores>
                    <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
                </passivation-stores>
                <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
                <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                    <data-stores>
                        <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                    </data-stores>
                </timer-service>
                <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
                <thread-pools>
                    <thread-pool name="default">
                        <max-threads count="10"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                    </thread-pool>
                </thread-pools>
                <default-security-domain value="other"/>
                <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
                <worker name="default"/>
                <buffer-pool name="default"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:2.0">
                <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                    <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                        <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                    </local-cache>
                    <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                        <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                    </local-cache>
                </cache-container>
                <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" aliases="sfsb">
                    <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                        <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                    </local-cache>
                    <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                        <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                    </local-cache>
                </cache-container>
                <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate">
                    <local-cache name="entity">
                        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                    </local-cache>
                    <local-cache name="local-query">
                        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                    </local-cache>
                    <local-cache name="timestamps">
                        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                        <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                    </local-cache>
                </cache-container>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:2.0">
                <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
                <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
                <default-workmanager>
                    <short-running-threads>
                        <core-threads count="50"/>
                        <queue-length count="50"/>
                        <max-threads count="50"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                    </short-running-threads>
                    <long-running-threads>
                        <core-threads count="50"/>
                        <queue-length count="50"/>
                        <max-threads count="50"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                    </long-running-threads>
                </default-workmanager>
                <cached-connection-manager/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
                <expose-resolved-model/>
                <expose-expression-model/>
                <remoting-connector/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
                <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
                <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                    <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
                </mail-session>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
                <remote-naming/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">
                <endpoint worker="default"/>
                <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:2.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
                <security-domains>
                    <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                        <authentication>
                            <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                                <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            </login-module>
                            <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                                <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            </login-module>
                        </authentication>
                    </security-domain>
                    <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                        <authorization>
                            <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                        </authorization>
                    </security-domain>
                    <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                        <authorization>
                            <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                        </authorization>
                    </security-domain>
                </security-domains>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0">
                <core-environment>
                    <process-id>
                        <uuid/>
                    </process-id>
                </core-environment>
                <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">
                <buffer-cache name="default"/>
                <server name="default-server">
                    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" record-request-start-time="true"/>
                    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                        <access-log pattern="%h %p %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %D &quot;%{i,X-Forwarded-For}&quot; &quot;%{i,True-Client-IP}&quot; &quot;%{i,JSESSIONID}c&quot;" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" prefix="access-log" worker="default" rotate="true"/>
                        <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                        <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    </host>
                </server>
                <servlet-container name="default">
                    <jsp-config/>
                    <websockets/>
                </servlet-container>

                <handlers>
                    <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
                </handlers>
                <filters>
                    <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
                    <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
                </filters>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
                <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
                <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
                <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                    <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                        <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                    </pre-handler-chain>
                </endpoint-config>
                <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:2.0"/>
        </profile>

        <interfaces>
            <interface name="management">
                <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
            </interface>
            <interface name="public">
                <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
            </interface>
            <interface name="unsecure">
                <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
            </interface>
        </interfaces>

        <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
            <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
            <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
            <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
            <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
            <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
                <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
        </socket-binding-group>

    </server>
  </code>  </pre>
```

What I desire is the access-log.log should produce logs for only access related information.

Also it should get rotated at the midnight that is 00:00:00hrs.

The standalone mentioned above is not able to implement the rotation at the desired time (00:00:00hrs).

So I tried making the following changes
    Instead of

```
 <root-logger>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
        <handler name="FILE"/>
    </handlers>
 </root-logger>
```

I am using

```
 <root-logger>
    <handlers>
         <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
         <handler name="FILE"/>
         <handler name="ACCESSFILE"/>
    </handlers>
 </root-logger>
```

But in this case the logs of server.log is also getting highlighted in the access-log.log

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The rotation issues is [known](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-678). Unfortunately the fix is only available in [WildFly 10.1.0.Final](http://wildfly.org/downloads/).